# Should *everything* be number/ numerically based on your resume?

Tags: resume, job-search, skills

If I'm describing what I did on a resume, do i necessarily need to say that I saved X, increased/ decreased Y, etc or, put another way, can I use stand-alone descriptions in my resume without the numbers when I need to describe what my job duties are, and there really aren't (or needn't be) any numbers behind what I'm saying?

Comment: Yes, you want to be as quantitative/objective as possible.

Comment: Important for your employer parameters should be quantified.

Comment: @PM77-1 "Employment parameters" means what, exactly?

Comment: If you are a manager then it could be the size of teams you managed,,  for a typist - words per minute,  for a pilot - total of flight hours,  etc.  Numbers can express your skills and experience and not just achievements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I'm describing what I did on a resume, do i necessarily need to say
>   that I saved X, increased/ decreased Y, etc or,

It depends on what you did. Were you an accountant? Or part of management?

> put another way, can I use stand-alone descriptions in my resume
>   without the numbers when I need to describe what my job duties are,
>   and there really aren't (or needn't be) any numbers behind what I'm
>   saying?

If numbers aren't required, don't use them. You may find quality more relevant that quantity.

Resume should list 2 or 3 tasks (and percent of time spent on them. These must add to 100%)

Under each task, you list sub-tasks such that it falls into

1. Situation
2. Action
3. Task (maybe lump this with Action)
4. Result

At the end of day, you need to connect your 2 or 3 tasks with the result that benefits your organization

Comment: I'm a technical writer and graphics person. I do what I'm told, and may not know the results from it because it's an "one off" project.